# how to send Image to server using uri?

Tags: android, image, retrofit

I am getting stuck when I draw a signature image and save in the phone directory I need to send an image to the server using retrofit I am getting stuck when creating Uri please check code?

```
  if (relativePath!=null) {


        val file = File(getRealPathFromURI(context, relativePath))
        val requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(
                MediaType.parse("image/*"),
                getRealPathFromURI(context, relativePath)
            )

        Log.d("@@sign", relativePath.toString())
        partsSign = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("sign", file.name, requestFile)
    }
```

My Uri is creating like that and it is not going to server :

another image uir is like that and it is working fine :

```
/@@photo: content://media/external/images/media/160


D/@@sign: file:///data/user/0/com.yesitlabs.empirebailsbond/app_Pictures/saved_images/Image-8162.png
```

for another image, it is working please help me

Comment: show glide code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
public static final String FORM_IMAGE = "multipart/form-data";
```

```java
MultipartBody.Part avatarRequest;
if (mFile != null) {
    RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse(Constants.PROFILE.FORM_IMAGE),
                    mFile
            );
    addRequestBody(name);
    avatarRequest =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(Constants.PROFILE.AVATAR, mFile.getName(), requestFile);
} else {
    avatarRequest = null;
}
```

Comment: i think you should replace "image/*" with "multipart/form-data"